# How can I access the object variable's fields to pass as the props to its child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that has another component to return.

```
var fieldValues = {
    firstName : null,
    lastName : null,
    gender : null,
    birthtday : null,
    dialingCode: null,
    mobileNumber : null,
    request_id: null,
    textCode : null,
    email : null,
    password : null,
    tagsSelectedList : [],
}

export default class SignUp extends React.Component {

    render() {
```

**update**

```
        return <SignUpTags
                    dialingCode = {fieldValues['dialingCode']}
                    mobileNumber = {fieldValues['mobileNumber']}
                    requestID = {fieldValues['request_id']}
                    nextStep={this.nextStep}
                    saveValues={this.saveValues}
                />
    }
}
```

When I load the page, I get the following errors:

> `dialingCode`, `mobileNumber` and `requestID` are all undefined.

How can I access the object variable's fieds to pass as the props to its child component?

Comment: Wrap keys to `''` - `fieldValues['dialingCode']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be `fieldValues['dialingCode']`, `fieldValues['mobileNumber']` and `fieldValues['requestId']`.

Note the `'`'s indicating they are key strings and aren't variables .

Comment: I have updated the code by wrapping the keys, also added the <SignUpTag> component. But the fields are still `undefined`.  Could you please have a look. Thank you.